# unlink not working with space in foldername path

Tags: php, spaces, unlink

I read a few threats on escaping but doesn't work. it works with a path without spaces fine....  ($subfolder contains spaces)

```
 $subfolder = "this a subf";
$filepath = "/var/www/domain/$subfolder/$imagetodelete";
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $filepath);
unlink($filepath); // correct if $subfolder/path contains no spaces
echo $filepath;
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Make sure you use `$filepath` in the unlink statement and not any constant, also you don't have to do a str_replace

Comment: I never heard that before. What PHP version is that?

Comment: Escaping should only be needed if you're trying to unlink using a shell command. Doing it with a function should work fine without any special processing.

Comment: hi.. it works fine  without any espcaping if the $subfolder contains no spaces...

Comment: @user3754240 And what's the question now?

Comment: using 5.3.3 php I cant get unlink to work if the file path contains a space..

Comment: unlink thrown a warning error?

Comment: @user3754240 Do you get any errors? (Error reporting: `<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`) Did you checked that the path and file is correct and if it's still there?

Comment: said permission denied? (only with foldername containing spaces"

Comment: delete Warning: unlink(/var/www/domain/2002 vacation trip/DCcoli.jpg): Permission denied in /var/www/domain/slideshow.php on line 405 /var/www/domain/2002 vacation trip/DCcoli.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $filepath);
```

The problem here is that you are escaping the space character in PHP, not actually inserting a backslash. In order to actually mean a backslash, you have to escape a backslash, like so:

```
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", $filepath);
```

Comment: or `'\ '` instead of `"\\ "`. But why you need that escaping? Whats the reason? I did never need that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone very much, when I downgraded to php 5.2 it worked. without str replace . it appears to be a BUG see Php - KB