# unlink not working with period (. dot) in foldername path

Tags: php, unlink

**Problem:**

`unlink()` is not working with a period `.` in the foldername path. It works without a period in the path though.

**What I have tried:**

I tried the escaping method. no luck.

```
$imagetodelete = $_GET['imagetodelete'];
$delete = $_GET['delete'];

if ($delete == "yes") {
error_reporting(E_ALL); #ini_set('display_errors', 1);



$dir = ('/var/www/example.com/pictures.gif.collection/');
```

directory

```
$dir = str_replace(".", "\\.", $dir);
```

and

```
$dir = str_replace(".", "\.", $dir);
```

I combined them into `$filepath`

```
 $filepath = "/www/example.com/pictures.gif.collection/$imagetodelete";
 unlink($filepath);
}
```

errors are Permission denied (if directory name has dots makes no sense)
php script, file to delete, and folder are all set to 777

the above only works if
     `$filepath = "/www/example.com/picturesgifcollection/image.jpg";` (no dots)

I also tried:
[unlink not working with space in foldername path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989096/unlink-not-working-with-space-in-foldername-path)

Comment: where is your unlink code?

Comment: You can't unlink a folder if has things in it.

Comment: This may help with clearing the files out of a folder before you try to delete the folder: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#109971 -- also, use `rmdir()` for deleting the folder itself when it is empty: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: im unlinking a image in a folder name iwth dots in it

Comment: You never have to escape any characters when calling functions like `unlink`. There's nothing special about `.` characters in directory names.

Comment: do you get any error? what's the file\directory permissions and owner set to?

Comment: I just tried deleting a file in a directory with `.` in the name, it worked fine.

Comment: thanks dragon, i turned on the error message Permission denied in line 30 of the file name i have but it set to 777 and the folder path /file to delete is all 777

Comment: ls -l slideshow.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23297 Nov 14 13:49 slideshow.php

Comment: do i have to add apache as a owner too?

Comment: root is owner, only root can delete (or people in the root grroup)

Comment: dragon how do i rate vote up u

Answer (score 0):

i posted this before,
the answer was permissions..  i set it to full root and it worked

thanks to Dragon genius